# How to get command line args with leading dash not being removed?

Tags: grails

It seems that leading dash in command line arguments passed to Grails scripts is removed. For example I have following script (scripts/Argstest.groovy):

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

target(main: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    println args
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

When I execute it like this:

```
grails> argstest - -- ---
```

I get following output:

```
-
--
```

Apparently leading dashes were removed. It is even more strange when I execute it like this:

```
grails> argstest - -a --b ---c
```

Output:

```
--c
-b
-a #leading dash not removed
```

How can I force Grails to give me **exactly** the same arguments that were passed to script and in the **same** order?

Answer (score 0):

Surround your arguments with quotation marks

Comment: I would prefer not to use quotation marks. But even if I do it, it still doesn't work as expected. For example "--a" gives "-a" (first dash is somehow cut off) and "-" gives no output at all.